# Freeze div that shifts from dynamically sized text

Tags: html, css

In the code below I have 3 divs, where the 1st and 3rd divs are tables that are filled with text of varying lengths (decided by the user) on a user submit.  The 2nd div is an image.  When a user submits and text is filled into the tables the center image (2nd div) moves depending on the length of text.  For example, if the longest word of either tables is on the left table, the image will shift to the right, along with the right table.  If the longest word in each table are the same length, nothing will move.

What CSS positioning can I use to ensure that the 2nd div stays centered no matter the length of text in the divs on either side of it?  Essentially I want the 1st div to expand to the left and the 3rd div expand to the right, so that any change in the length of the `<span>` will not move the centered image at all

```
<div class="text_tables" id="left_table">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span class="output render" id="text1"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="text_tables">
    <img id="img1" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/img.png') }}">
</div>
<div class="text_tables" id="right_table">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span class="output render" id="text6"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, to honor those who say that tables shouldn't be used for layout, I've put together a little [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/BQ94H/7/) with just divs.

Is this the type of behavior you're looking for?

HTML

```
<div class='holderdiv'>
  <div class='leftdiv'> asdfasdfasdf</div>
  <div class='centerdiv'></div>
  <div class='rightdiv'>ASDASDFASDFASDFASDF </div>
</div>
```

---

V 2.0

Ok, this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/BQ94H/7/) seems to do much of what you want.

I'm a bit confused about exactly what you want. Do we need to parse all of the spaces out and line up the words in a single column in either wing?

Provide more details, and I can spiff it up a bit more.

Comment: Unfortunately, not really.  Regardless of the length of the words on either side of the image, the picture should always remain in the center.  In your fiddle, the text the right div, which is longer, should move onto a second line instead of pushing the photo to the left.

Comment: How do you want to enter the text? Directly into both sides with a textarea? Or from an input/textarea field that that then populates both sides?

Comment: The latter - I have an input area below all of this.  On the input submit the text populates the area on either side of the image.